# upgrade from VS2010 Beta1 to Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to upgrade from VS2010 beta 1 to beta 2 ?
I don't want to download  full beta 2 version !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect so. IIRC, there isn't even a guaranteed uninstall for beta 1 - the idea is that you either install it in a VM, or on an OS you don't mind wiping if it doesn't uninstall cleanly (I wouldn't try ringing support if it goes screwy...).

You're going to have to download the full beta 2. Ultimately, there is no long-term benefit in supporting this option (an upgrade path between beta 1 and beta 2) - as it **isn't** part of their supported product base, and it introduces extra variables, which you **don't** want during a beta. Download the full thing and reinstall. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No, you actually *have* to uninstall Beta1 to install Beta2. What's the big deal, it is not all that large of a download.

Comment: so actually its a big deal (2G download) !

Answer (score 0):

There is no "upgrade" that only installs the parts that have changed.  If you want to install VS2010 B2 you'll have to download the whole enchilada.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. You cannot install Beta 2 over Beta 1 - when I tried it forced me to uninstall Beta 1 first